# Can't log in - get Caps lock is on error - but Caps lock is not on

Tags: login

I AM A NEWBIE

I have been using Ubuntu for a couple of months now.
This morning when I started up my computer and went to log in, I keep getting an error message that says "Caps lock is on." BUT it is not on. It seems to be triggered when I type the 3 key, which is part of my password.

My current version of Ubuntu is 21.10, linus E502NA TTy3

I did ask for me to update the version yesterday evening not long before I turned the computer off for the night.

Please help. In non-technical jargon.

Comment: I think you need to consider a hardware (ie keyboard) issue. If it’s a dual boot system, see what happens in the other os. If single os, try booting into a live usb session and see what happens when you type 3 etc. Alternatively (if you can get one), try a different keyboard - that’s probably the easiest if you have the available spare hardware. Obviously if it’s a hardware issue there isn’t anything software can do to fix it (though using a login that doesn’t require the offending 3 is a short term workaround).

Comment: Hello Will. I only have Ubuntu on the computer. I tried using an external keyboard and was able to login. If I use the regular keyboard, (in libreoffice for example) I get all kinds of strange characters. could it be due to the update that was installed yesterday evening?

Answer (score 1):

Turn CapsLock on. System would think it's off.

Comment: turning it on did not correct the problem. still getting strange characters.

Comment: Have you tried reboot?